# Extracting Part of Speech (Source and Destinations) using text mining/NLP?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, text-mining, nltk, stanford-nlp

I need to extract the source and destination terms from the text
 documents using text mining / NLP / Information Retrieval ?

Example input:

> 1. I am travelling from New York to London.
> 2. I am heading towards playground from home.
> 3. I will be going to Sweden from Boston.
> 4. I was flying from School to Home.

The output can be as follows :

```
S. No. |  source    | Destination
------ |  ----------|------------
      1| New York   | London
      2| playground | home
      3| Sweden     | Boston
      4| School     | Home
```

Answer (score 2):

Named Entity Recognition is technique which can be used here. Location is one of the 3 most studied classes (with Person and Organization). Stanford NLP has an [open source](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/CRF-NER.shtml) Java implementation that is extremely powerful.

For Example  let say sentence is "**i will be going to Sweden from Boston.**" 
[image: Stanford NER Demo]

Now here you can use [regular expression](https://lost-contact.mit.edu/afs/cs.pitt.edu/projects/nltk/docs/tutorial/regexps/nochunks.html) to detect these **LOCATION** tags.